# angular stateless components passing classes vs chunks

Tags: angularjs, angular, stateless

I read a lot about how cool stateless components are but I didn't find them very cool when trying it out =). Maybe I missed the point?

For example, I have the components:

```
<list data="data" lastSelected="lastSelected" listType="listType" setLastSelected="setLastSelected"></list>

<filter data="data" filter="filter" defaultFilter="defaultFilter" filteredLength="filteredLength"></filter>
```

So the argument for this is, you can overwrite all those attributes data and functions; so the components are super flexible and can be reused.

What I do is this:

```
<list store="store"></list>
<filter filterClass="filterClass"></filter>
```

I still can overwrite everything if I just extend the `filterClass` for example and my html looks a lot cleaner and my JS looks the same.

So can somebody explain to me why the first version is better?